# How to add data from tk.Entry to f'string in Python 3?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

I need to make a text generator in which user input is added to f'string. What I get in result is that data typed in entry can be printed in PyCharm console, but doesn't show up in generated strings in tk.Text. Thank you in advance!

Here is the code of my randomizer:

Simple GUI interface:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('TEXT MACHINE')
win.geometry('1020x600+400+250')
win.resizable(False, False)
```

Here I want a variable anchor to assign a data from entry

```
anchor = tk.StringVar() 
entry_1 = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=anchor)
entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, sticky='wn')

def add_text():
    text_generated = (random.choice(first_text) + random.choice(second_text)
                      )
    text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text.insert('insert', text_generated)

btn_1 = tk.Button(win, text='GENERATE TEXT', command=add_text, height=5, width=50)
btn_1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

lbl_1 = tk.Label(win, text='Place Your Anchor Here')
lbl_1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, sticky='ws')

text = tk.Text(win, width=120)
text.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=(20, 120))

win.grid_rowconfigure(0, pad=50)
win.grid_columnconfigure(0, pad=50)

first_text = ['First text 1', 
              'First text 2', 
              'First text 3'
              ]
second_text = [f'Second text 1{anchor.get()}',
               f'Second text 2{anchor.get()}',
               f'Second text 3{anchor.get()}'
              ]
```

When I generate text I get empty space instead of anchor, but when I do `print(anchor.get())` it shows up in my console correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're essentially calling `anchor.get()` immediately after declaring it with `anchor = tk.StringVar()`. It seems like what you really want is `entry_1.get()`, in which case you can do away with the `anchor` variable entirely.

```
entry_1 = tk.Entry(win)
```

You'll also probably want to move the definition of `second_text` (and maybe also `first_text`, for consistency) to *inside* the `add_text()` function. That way the call to `entry_1.get()` is performed on each button press instead of immediately (and only once)

```
def add_text():
    first_text = ['First text 1', 'First text 2', 'First text 3']
    second_text = [
        f'Second text 1{entry_1.get()}',
        f'Second text 2{entry_1.get()}',
        f'Second text 3{entry_1.get()}'
    ]
    text_generated = (random.choice(first_text) + random.choice(second_text))
    text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text.insert('insert', text_generated)
```

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept this answer so others know this question has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: Sure. I realized that I forget that If I want to use something, I need to explain it before (I was putting first/second text under text_generated function.) Thank you again!